# Onmouseover method dynamically allocating

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a set of elements from CMS. I have reproduced the problem here with a set of rectangles that are being generated in Javascript. How can I dynamically add a "onmouseover" method to each one of them, that changes the colour of the block hovered?

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var coloured_div = document.createElement("div");
  coloured_div.className = "col_div_class";
  coloured_div.id = "coloured_div" + i;
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(coloured_div);

  coloured_div.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverCube);
}

function hoverCube(i) {
  document.getElementById("coloured_div" + i).style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}
```

```css
.col_div_class {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid white 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're passing `hoverCube` as a callback to your event listener, it automatically gets passed an object which has information about the event (`e`). From this information, you can get the element which triggered the event by doing (`e.target`), which you can then set the style of:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var coloured_div = document.createElement("div");
  coloured_div.className = "col_div_class";
  coloured_div.id = "coloured_div" + i;
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(coloured_div);

  coloured_div.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverCube);
}

function hoverCube(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}
```

```css
.col_div_class {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid white 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Alternatively, to achieve what you're trying to do in your code, you need to pass `i` as a parameter to `hoverCube`, which will then be able to access the correct element:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var coloured_div = document.createElement("div");
  coloured_div.className = "col_div_class";
  coloured_div.id = "coloured_div" + i;
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(coloured_div);

  coloured_div.addEventListener("mouseover", (function(i) { // ES5 closure (if using ES6 you can simply change var i to let i in the for loop)
      return function() {
        hoverCube(i);
      };
    })(i)
)}

function hoverCube(i) {
  document.getElementById("coloured_div" + i).style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}
```

```css
.col_div_class {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid white 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Append event listener to all elements. Select them with `querySelectorAll`. No `id`s needed.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var coloured_div = document.createElement("div");
  coloured_div.className = "col_div_class";
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(coloured_div);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.col_div_class').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  });
});
```

```css
.col_div_class {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid white 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body"></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here. The first is to use just CSS to accomplish the task.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var coloured_div = document.createElement("div");
  coloured_div.className = "col_div_class";
  coloured_div.id = "coloured_div" + i;
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(coloured_div);
}
```

```css
.col_div_class {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid white 5px;
}

.col_div_class:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

If you must use Javascript, please see below.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var coloured_div = document.createElement("div");
  coloured_div.className = "col_div_class";
  coloured_div.id = "coloured_div" + i;
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(coloured_div);
  coloured_div.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "orange";});
  coloured_div.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";});
}
```

```css
.col_div_class {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid white 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Comment: Good point using CSS, I sometimes forget this option exists.. My use case is more complex than this, so I will need to use JS. I will go with the e.target solution.. Thanks!